# Why setting contentsGravity other than kCAGravityCenter has no effect on CALayer?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, calayer

I am setting `contentsGravity` to the Layer Hosted `NSView` as follow but it only works for `kCAGravityCenter`. Also from Apple docs, it is mentioned to use `layerContentsForContentsScale` which I have implemented in my code.

> layerContentsForContentsScale:
>
> Use this method in situations where you want to use the image as the contents of a layer. This method provides the image data wrapped in an object that correctly respects all of the possible content gravities supported by the layer.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, CALayerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       view.wantsLayer = true

       let imageLayer = CALayer()
       imageLayer.delegate = self
       imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 500.0, height: 500.0)
       imageLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor

       view.layer?.addSublayer(imageLayer)
       imageLayer.setNeedsDisplay()

    }

   func display(_ layer: CALayer) {
       layer.contents = NSImage(named:"test")?.layerContents(forContentsScale: 1.0)
       layer.contentsGravity = "kCAGravityTopLeft"
   }

}
```

If `contentsGravity` is not set the Image correctly fills the bound of layer. When contentsGravity is set to `kCAGravityCenter`, the image correctly center to the bound. For any other `contentsGravity` constants there is no effect.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: The ``kCA...`` family is a family of *constants* that represent *strings*, but in each case, the represented string is **not** simply the same value as the constant. For example ``kCAGravityTopLeft`` represents the string "topLeft"`, and it is this string that the ``contentsGravity`` property recognises. So you want ``layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTopLeft``, or ``layer.contentsGravity = "topLeft"``

Comment: @PaulPatterson, I must have overlooked that fact. Thanks.